# NumPy: how to "scale" an array "smoothly"

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a numpy array like this

```
array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11])
```

And I would like to "scale" it by a factor of two, filling in the "gaps" using the mean of two adjacent numbers. Result:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11])
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple function you can use.

```py
def double_list(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        new_arr.append(arr[i])
        if i == 0 or i == len(arr) - 1:
            new_arr.append(arr[i])
        else:
            new_arr.append(int((arr[i] + arr[i + 1]) / 2))
    return new_arr


print(double_list(arr))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it works well. I thought that there would be a built-in function. But this solution is good enough for me.

Comment: to quote the zen of python "Simple is better than complex."

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy [arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) function

```
arr = np.array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11])

arr2 = np.arange(arr.min(),arr.max() + 1)
print(arr2)
```

Output:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
```

To get the output as per your requirement

```
arr2 = np.append(np.arange(arr.min(),arr.max() + 1), arr.max())
print(arr2)
```

Output:

```
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 11]
```